# Applications and Website blocker for improving concentration with specific time windows

Tags: productivity

Do you know a program working on Ubuntu by which I can block certain apps and websites. I do know certain paid services for Windows/Mac/Android, including firefox plugins (also for Linux) etc, which allow to block certain programs and apps to run at specific times during the day. On Android I am using the service freedom.to. Do you know a similar service, paid or opensource program, running on ubuntu, or some command line version thereof? I need to improve my productivity during my working hours. The browser plugins of freedom.to running on linux are not optimal, since they can easily be circumvented, by switching to private mode, or an alternative browser.

Comment: Any block **you** setup can be overcome by **you**.. Adjust your willpower.

Comment: @waltinator, often, trust in will power might be overly optimistic, especially in my case. Every block can be overcome of course by myself, but it might be setup in a way that makes time consuming or slightly complicated, so there might be some benefit, still. 
Putting this aside, what blocking methods can you think of, in general, on ubuntu?